# Tiagra 4600 trigger shifters, 10-speed 105 RD-5701-GS derailleur and 11-32 cassette compatible?

Tags: shimano, cassette, derailleur-rear, shifter, compatibility

My Cannondale Quick 1 Carbon has Tiagra 4600 trigger shifters, a 10-speed 105 RD-5701-SS derailleur and a 12-30 cassette.

I would like to change to a 11-32 cassette, and understand that I would therefore need to use a medium GS derailleur. Will a RD-5701-GS work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the RD-5701-GS would work for a 11-32 cassette if you stick to a double crankset. If you ever change for a triple crankset, the maximum low sprocket size with the GS is 30T.

See the [RD-5701 specifications](https://productinfo.shimano.com/#/spec/ROAD/Rear%20Derailleur?q=rd-5701&header=false&matchmodel=1) for details.

Comment: Thank you Ollie for your precise answer.

Comment: @MalcolmRatcliffe I am glad I could help. If you are happy with the answer, feel free to click on the checkmark beside it to mark it as accepted.